# I am trying to append/concatenate my vector in R, but it will only concatenate my last value, how can i get all of them to be concatenated?

Tags: r, vector, concatenation

```
for(i in 1:length(freqy1)){
ps11 = rbeta(1, (1 + freqy1[i]), (1 + (freqy1[i]/50)))
    ps11_v = list(c(ps11))
    print(ps11)
    for(i in 1:length(freqy1)){
        ps11_v = c(ps11_v, ps11)
    }
    ps12 = 1 - (rbeta(1, (1 + freqy1[i]), (1 + (freqy1[i]/50))))
    #print(ps12)
}
print("VECTOR VECTOR VECTOR")
print(ps11_v)
```

It will only print out that last value of ps11_v (but it prints the length of freqy1), how can I have it such that each ps11 value gets added to my vector?

Comment: you have the same counter variable `i` in both loops!

Comment: `rbeta` is vectorized, so you can do `ps11<-rbeta(length(freqy1),1+freqy1,1+freqy1/50)` without writing a loop.

Comment: hmm.. no that wasn't he problem :( thanks though!

Comment: nvm! your' second comment worked!! THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace your code by:

```
ps11 <- rbeta(length(freqy1),1+freqy1,1+freqy1/50)
ps12 <- 1 - ps11
```

to achieve the desired result.